# Run Python script on Windows from within different Python environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, arcgis

I want to use some Python modules I have installed for my standard Python installation from within a Python prompt in ArcGIS Pro. The script that I run in ArcGIS Pro should be easily transferable to other machines and usable without adding modules to the ArcGIS Pro Python installation. To this end, I tried to do the following:

1. Write a Python script that runs in ArcGIS Pro
2. Write another Python script from within the first script and call it (in a temporary directory)
3. Save the data generated from within the second script and load it in the parent script
   However, `os.system("py C:\\path\\to\\script2.py")` fails with exit status `1`.
   The second script runs fine, however, when I just double-click it or run it from within a command prompt outside ArcGIS Pro Python Notebook.

What is the problem here and how can I solve it?

The code I used (MWE):

```
import os
test = 1

import tempfile
tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
tmp_iNat_py_code = '''#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
test = 1

import pickle
with open(os.path.join(tmp_dir, "iNatList" + ".pkl"), "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(test, f)
'''

iNatScript = os.path.join(tmp_dir, "tmp_iNat.py")
with open(iNatScript, "w") as f:
    f.write(tmp_iNat_py_code)

import platform
OS = platform.system()
python_path = f"python3 {iNatScript}" if OS == "Linux" else f"py {iNatScript}"
os.system(python_path)

import pickle
with open(os.path.join(tmp_dir, "iNatList" + ".pkl"), "rb") as f:
    iNat_data = pickle.load(f)
```

Full code:

```
project_ID = "some_project_name"

## get iNaturalist data by running script in Python environment with iNat API installed
import tempfile
tmp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
tmp_iNat_py_code = '''#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from pyinaturalist import *
observations = []
page_results = [1]
p = 1
while len(page_results) > 0:
    page = get_observations(project_id = \"''' + project_ID +\
                            '''\",taxon_id = 47362, per_page = 30, page = p)
    page_results = page["results"]
    observations += page_results
    p += 1

tmp_dir = r"''' + tmp_dir +\
'''"
iNat_data = list()
for obs in observations:
    if obs["description"] is not None and obs["description"] != "":
        lat = obs["location"][0]
        lon = obs["location"][1]
        id = obs["id"]
        taxon = obs["taxon"]["name"]
        url = obs["uri"]
        quality = obs["quality_grade"]
        iNat_data.append([id, lat, lon, taxon, url, quality])

import pickle
with open(os.path.join(tmp_dir, "iNatList" + ".pkl"), "wb") as f:
    pickle.dump(iNat_data, f)
'''

iNatScript = os.path.join(tmp_dir, "tmp_iNat.py")
with open(iNatScript, "w") as f:
    f.write(tmp_iNat_py_code)

import platform
OS = platform.system()
python_path = f"python3 {iNatScript}" if OS == "Linux" else f"py {iNatScript}"
os.system(python_path)

import pickle
with open(os.path.join(tmp_dir, "iNatList" + ".pkl"), "rb") as f:
    iNat_data = pickle.load(f)
```

Comment: Can you configure ArcGIS Pro to use your systems Python interpreter? That would be preferable to running a script from within another script

Comment: I'll have to check, but I definitely need to also use the ArcGIS Pro built-in interpreter, since I also need some of the functions there and it is not open source (the ```ArcPy``` module only works with the ArcGIS Pro installation (there might be a work around, but I also want this to be easy to configure since I might share the script with people without any Python knowledge))

Comment: Have you attempted the "temp py code" as a standalone code outside of ArcGIS pro env?